# Is there exists any Function to get Category link for multisite Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks

Is there any function that exists like for getting category link in `Wordpress` for multisite network like the the function  `get_blog_permalink($blog_id, $post_id)`  for getting a permalink for posts across multisite network?

Any Help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there isn't for now. the only way to do it is to query to the database yourself.